# Getting an uncaught exception while iterating through result set in iOS sqlite DB

Tags: ios, sqlite, uncaught-exception

following snippet gives me :

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-    [__NSCFString count]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8ce0c00'

```
-(void)loadInfo{
    // Create the query.
    NSString *query = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"select * from tableName where      category=\"%@\" ", @"cat1"];

    // Load the relevant data.
    NSArray *results = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:[self.dbManager loadDataFromDB:query]];
    NSMutableArray *List = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    NSLog(@"Count..:%d",results.count); 

    for(int i=0; i<results.count; i++){
        List = [[results objectAtIndex:i] objectAtIndex:[self.dbManager.arrColumnNames indexOfObject:@"itemName"]];
    }
    NSLog(@"Result..:::: %d", [List count]);
}
```

What is going wrong here? Cant i print List count? dbmanager is what I have implemented using eg. given in - http://www.appcoda.com/sqlite-database-ios-app-tutorial/

Comment: Did you Google "unrecognized selector"???

Comment: You assign an `NSString` to `List`. It's not an `NSArray`.

Comment: And what's the point of the loop? In the end, `List` will be equal to the last value. All prior values are ignored.

Comment: And why initialize List with `[[NSMutableArray alloc]init]` when you're going to overwrite the pointer a few lines later?

Comment: Don't use names beginning with an upper case character for variable names.  Initial upper case should only be used for class names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This operation replaces `List` on every loop iteration with a different object:

```
List = [[results objectAtIndex:i] objectAtIndex:[self.dbManager.arrColumnNames indexOfObject:@"itemName"]];
```

Judging from the error, the object happens to be `NSString`.

What you probably wanted is to add objects to your mutable array `List`:

```
[List addObject:[[results objectAtIndex:i] objectAtIndex:[self.dbManager.arrColumnNames indexOfObject:@"itemName"]]];
```